# Complex count based on the latest date of a month

Tags: sql, django

I have a model:

```
class HistoricalRecord(models.Model):
    history_id = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    history_date = models.DateField()
```

How can I get the count of each type of `HistoricalRecord` by getting only the latest object (based on the history_id) for a given month. For example:

With these example objects:

```
HistoricalRecord.objects.create(history_id="ABC1", type="A", history_date=date(2000, 10, 5))
HistoricalRecord.objects.create(history_id="ABC1", type="A", history_date=date(2000, 10, 27))
HistoricalRecord.objects.create(history_id="DEF1", type="A", history_date=date(2000, 10, 16))
HistoricalRecord.objects.create(history_id="ABC1", type="B", history_date=date(2000, 10, 8))
```

The result should be:

```
[
    {
        "type": "A",
        "type_count": 2
    },
    {
        "type": "B",
        "type_count": 0
    }
]
```

"A" is 2 because the latest `HistoryRecord` object with history_id "ABC1" is on the 27th and the type is A; the other one is the record with history_id "DEF1".

I've tried:

```
HistoricalRecord.objects.filter(history_date__range(month_start, month_end)).order_by("type").values("type").annotate(type_count=Count("type"))
```

but obviously this is incorrect since it gets all the values for the month. The structure of the result doesn't have to be exactly like above, as long as it clearly conveys the count of each type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can likely be done with .extra(), add this to the query:

```
.extra(
    where=["""history_date = (SELECT MAX(history_date) FROM historical_record hr
                              WHERE hr.history_id = historical_record.history_id
                                    AND hr.history_date < %s)"""],
    params=[month_end]
)
```